# Select a cell value given the current month

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking for a bit of help on something. I've a total displayed for each month (with different years of course), for example 39.99€ for Dec-19. In November 2019, I'd like to see this amount in my orange cell. In December 2019 I'd like to see the amount for January 2020, etc...

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Edouard

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Index Match:

```
=INDEX(I:I,MATCH(EDATE(TODAY(),1),A:A))
```